# Getting value from a map within a list

Tags: java

Assuming that you have the following :

```
List<Map<String,Object>> test;
```

How can you retrieve a value from test, when the key is "key1".

I tried the following :

```
int number = ((Integer)test.get(0).get("key1"));
```

but it does not work ..

Comment: You have object in the second one of map change it to Integer.

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean? Is there an error? Is the value different from what you expected? Explain.

Comment: Also, could the key you're looking for be in any of the maps? Do you want to check all of them? What happens if it appears in more than one map, with different values?

Comment: Does your map contain `Integer objects` as `Object objects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
    Map<String, Integer> ohm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<HashMap<String,Integer>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();

    ohm.put("one", 1);
    ohm.put("two", 2);

    test.add((HashMap)ohm);

    int number = test.get(0).get("two");
    System.out.println(number);
```

If your HashMap contains, **--String, Object-- and NOT  --String, Integer--** the following should help.

```
    Map<String, Object> ohm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    ohm.put("one", 1);
    ohm.put("two", 2);

    test.add((HashMap)ohm);

    int number = (Integer)test.get(0).get("one");
    System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over your list and look for the map that contains the key I guess:

```
Object value = null;
for(Map<String,Object> map : test) {
    if(map.containsKey("key1")) {
        value = map.get("key1");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My reputation is not high enough to write a comment so I'll send you an answer instead.

Actually, I'm not sure in which context you would need this structure exactly.

You could use `Map<String, List<Object>> test;` instead. Then, you would retrieve your value like this:

```
List<Object> values = test.get("key1");
Integer value = (Integer) values.get(0);
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to suggest that kind of structure change without knowing exactly what the OP wants; the two of them have considerably different use cases.